# Filling up a matrix with computed values of another matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix

I did not find an answer in other posts, nor did i understand them if they handled similar topics, since i am relatively new to R and to programming in general. I have the following survey output X that i am working with (extract):

```
A1B1         A1B2       A1B3          A1B4          A2B1          A2B2        A2B3      ...
-0.37014356  1.08841141 -0.126574243 -0.59169360  1.682673457 -0.427706432 -0.76091938  ...
3.03017573  1.39812421  0.243516558 -4.67181650 -0.378640756  2.039940436 -0.40785893   ...
3.50183121  1.51249433 -0.775449944 -4.23887560 -0.456911873  0.431838943  0.91108052   ...
```

...

I want to compute the difference of the maximum range `diff(range(X[i,n:m]))` of the first 4 (with `n:m` equals `1:4`), the second 4 `(5:8)` and the third 4 `(9:12)` columns of every row i of X and put the results into a second matrix with i rows and 3 columns.

E.g. for the first row and the first 4 cols, it would be `1.08841141+0.59169360=1.68010501.`

For this purpose i created a new matrix and tried to fill it up with the values:

```
newmatrix <- matrix(0,nrow(X),3)
newmatrix[1:nrow(X),1] <- for (i in (1:nrow(X))) {diff(range(X[i,1:4]))}  
newmatrix[1:nrow(X),2] <- for (i in (1:nrow(X))) {diff(range(X[i,5:8]))}   
newmatrix[1:nrow(X),3] <- for (i in (1:nrow(X))) {diff(range(X[i,9:12]))}
```

I get the output error:

```
Error in newmatrix[1:nrow(RBetas), 1] <- for (i in (1:nrow(RBetas))) { : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the block of columns are based on the first two characters, i.e. `A1`, `A2`,  we can split this into different blocks by using `substr` to extract the first two characters from the column names and use this as index to `split`.  Then, we can either use `apply` with `range` and `diff` to get the result or use `pmax` and `pmin`.

```
  indx <- substr(colnames(df), 1,2)
```

If the grouping is not based on the `column names` but on the position, this should also work

```
  indx <- (1:ncol(df)-1)%/%4 +1


  res1 <- sapply(split(seq_len(ncol(df)), indx),
               function(i) do.call(pmax,df[,i, drop=FALSE])-
                                 do.call(pmin, df[,i, drop=FALSE]))
```

Or

```
 res2 <- sapply(split(seq_len(ncol(df)), indx),
            function(i) apply(df[,i, drop=FALSE], 1,
                          function(x) diff(range(x))) )



 identical(res1, res2)
 #[1] TRUE
 res1
 #        A1       A2
 #[1,] 1.680105 2.443593
 #[2,] 7.701992 2.447799
 #[3,] 7.740707 1.367992
```

Or using your code

```
 newmatrix <- matrix(0, nrow(df), 2) #here the example dataset is only 7 columns
 for(i in (1:nrow(df))) newmatrix[i,1] <-  diff(range(df[i,1:4]))
 for(i in (1:nrow(df))) newmatrix[i,2] <-  diff(range(df[i,5:7]))
 newmatrix
 #    [,1]     [,2]
 #[1,] 1.680105 2.443593
 #[2,] 7.701992 2.447799
 #[3,] 7.740707 1.367992
```

If you have many blocks of columns, you can try a double `for` loop

```
 lst <- split(seq_len(ncol(df)), indx) #keep the columns to group in a `list`
 newmatrix <- matrix(0, nrow(df), 2) #he
 for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
 for(j in seq_along(lst)){
   newmatrix[i,j] <- diff(range(df[i, lst[[j]]]))
  }
 }

newmatrix
#      [,1]     [,2]
#[1,] 1.680105 2.443593
#[2,] 7.701992 2.447799
#[3,] 7.740707 1.367992
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A1B1 = c(-0.37014356, 3.03017573, 3.50183121), 
A1B2 = c(1.08841141, 1.39812421, 1.51249433), A1B3 = c(-0.126574243, 
0.243516558, -0.775449944), A1B4 = c(-0.5916936, -4.6718165, 
-4.2388756), A2B1 = c(1.682673457, -0.378640756, -0.456911873
), A2B2 = c(-0.427706432, 2.039940436, 0.431838943), A2B3 = c(-0.76091938, 
-0.40785893, 0.91108052)), .Names = c("A1B1", "A1B2", "A1B3", 
"A1B4", "A2B1", "A2B2", "A2B3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you akrun you solved all my questions! :)